# Android action bar position change

Tags: android, android-actionbar, position

I would like to position another view above the Android action bar- same as in the Yahoo Weather app (when pulling to refresh).
How can I move (set the y position, with\without animation) the Android action bar to another location. Is it possible? or do they use a custom Action bar that only looks like the standard one?

Comment: What makes you think Yahoo Weather App even has an action bar?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can not change Android ActionBar position on Screen. You must remove default ActionBar in theme and use your own implementation.